# Search values in string while looping - stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table_a is containing the following information:

```
Category Step Value1
1   1   Apple
1   2   Orange
1   3   Pineapple
2   1   Red
2   2   Blue
2   3   Yellow
2   4   Green
3   1   Water
3   2   Wind
```

My table_b is containing the following information:

```
value_field
I like to eat an orange apple.
Which fruit is orange?
Which person lives in water and in a pineapple?
Ones a month I put up a red flag. 
Blue is the color of water.
It seems there is a disease called yellow fiver.
Our planet should be more green.
There should be more places with drinkable water
Could we use wind as energy in more places?
```

I want to make a stored procedure which loops through the categories by the different steps to get the following information using Patindex to see if a table_a.value is within table_b.value_field.
Producing the following output:

| Category | Step1 | Step2 | Step3 | Step4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I like to eat an orange apple. | 25 | 18 | 0 | 0 |
| Which fruit is orange? | 0 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
| Which person lives in water and in a pineapple? | 0 | 0 | 38 | 0 |

| Category | Step1 | Step2 | Step3 | Step4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ones a month I put up a red flag. | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Blue is the color of water. | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| It seems there is a disease called yellow fiver. | 0 | 0 | 36 | 0 |

| Category | Step1 | Step2 | Step3 | Step4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Our planet should be more green. | 0 | 0 | 0 | 27 |
| There should be more places with drinkable water | 44 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Could we use wind as energy in more places? | 0 | 14 | 0 | 0 |

I created the following code as a start to loop through table_a, but i am a little bit lost how i now should implement this with table_b. I was thinking about doing a join, but don't now if this is the best thing to do.

```
DECLARE @Val1 INT,
    @Val1_end INT,
    @Val2 INT,
    @Val2_end INT,
    @UOM nvarchar(250)
       
SET @Val1 = (select min(category) from table_a)
SET @Val1_end = (select max(category) from table_a)
    
WHILE @Val1 <= @val1_end
        BEGIN
            SET @Val2 = (select min(step) from table_a)
            SET @Val2_end = (select max(step) from table_a where category = @val1)
            WHILE @Val2 <= @Val2_end
            
                BEGIN 
                
                    SET @UOM = '%'+ (select value1 from table_a where category = @val1 and step=@val2 ) +'%'
                    
                    select value_field
                    ,Patindex(@UOM,value_field) where step = 1
                    ,Patindex(@UOM,value_field) where step = 2
                    ,Patindex(@UOM,value_field) where step = 3
                    ,Patindex(@UOM,value_field) where step = 4
                    from table_b
                    
                    SET @Val2 = @Val2 + 1
      
                END
            SET @Val1 = @Val1 + 1
        END
```

Could somebody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: In your first example 3rd line, why is there no step1 value for *Water*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
; WITH kvRows AS (
    SELECT  a.Category, 
            a.Step, 
            a.Value1, 
            b.value_field, 
            pos = PATINDEX('%'+a.Value1+'%', b.value_field)
    FROM #table_a a
    INNER JOIN #table_b b
    ON PATINDEX('%'+a.Value1+'%', b.value_field) > 0
) 
SELECT  x.Category, 
        r.value_field, 
        x.Step1, 
        x.Step2, 
        x.Step3, 
        x.Step4 
FROM kvRows r
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    --- pivot rows to columns using "VALUES"
    (Category, IIF(Step=1, pos, 0), IIF(Step=2, pos, 0), IIF(Step=3, pos, 0), IIF(Step=4,pos,0)) 
) as x(Category, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need a Loop here, Instead, Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        A.Category,
        A.Step,
        A.Value1,
        B.Value_field
    FROM TABLE_A A
        INNER JOIN TABLE_B B 
            ON CHARINDEX(A.Value1,B.Value_field)>0
)
SELECT  
    Category = Value_field,
    Step1 = [1],
    Step2 = [2],
    Step3 = [3],
    Step4 = [4]
    FROM CTE
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Category)
        FOR
        Step IN
        (
            [1],[2],[3],[4]
        )
    )Q
```